# What is the limit of the returned rows from a select statement for the SOCI Firebird backend?

Tags: firebird, soci

Using SOCI Firebird v4.0 trunk to Read/Write data from/to a Firebird database.

The problem is, when I select all the rows from a table that are over 2 million rows via a select statement, SOCI throws an `std::bad_alloc` exception and I get only exactly the value of **1024 * 1024** rows that is: **1048576**

I don't know if SOCI has a limit or there is something else I am missing here!

BTW I am storing the rows in a `std::vector`.

Comment: Firebird itself as no such limit. I don't know SOCI, but maybe you need to look for a way to stream results instead of attempting to retrieve all rows at once. In any case, you need to post the necessary code to reproduce this and the full error information (a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither SOCI nor Firebird was responsible for this.
The only cause was the system itself that ran out of memory and can't handle over **2^32** on **32-bit** version.
I had to recompile the code in **64-bit** and test it in a **64-bit** system.